# Database Model for Question-Answers in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have:

- Quizzes, each quiz contains multiple questions.
- Questions, each question has a label, maximum 4 images, a question type(multiple correct, single correct, fill in the blank). Each question might have options.
- Each option has a label and might have 1 image associated with it.

Currently, I have made it as:

```
create table quizzes (
    id uuid primary key,
    title ascii,
    questions set<uuid>,
    created_at timeuuid,
    updated_at timeuuid
);
create type options_info (
  label ascii,
  image uuid
);
create table questions (
    id uuid primary key,
    label ascii,
    images list<uuid>,
    options set<options_info>,
    type uuid,
    updated_at timeuuid
);
create table question_type (
    id uuid,
    name ascii,
    primary key(id, name)
);
create table images (
    id uuid primary key,
    image blob,
    caption ascii,
    uploaded_at timeuuid
);
```

Euhm, I think there can be a better model than I've made. Any improvements?
Also, I wish to save which option is the correct one. I am a bit stuck at making out the best possible structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that you're thinking in relational while data modeling a nosql database.
First Rule is: you better use de-normalized tables in a way that no join or foreign keys be needed in your queries, so it could be handled with one or two table.

Please read this thorough first:
https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling

Comment: hmm...yeah I am new to NoSQL.